# Excel Userform Textbox Constant Set Focus

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

First of all I would like to thank all of you guys. Maybe you did not notice but you help me to grasp VBA to some level from scratch. I am still in learning process so I may be missing something really simple, please be gentle :)

First of all I would like to give a small backgroud update about my issue. I have been writing a small program to scan incoming parts to my work to be able to keep inventory status. Latest look of the program is like below:

[image]

And numbers on the picture are my nightmares lately:

**1. Scanned Part Number:** This is the textbox where scanner inputs the value. After I receive the input I immidietly convert that data to a variable and clear the textbox value as below:

```
Private Sub PN_CurrentScan_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        EnteredPN = Replace(PN_CurrentScan.Value, Chr(32), "", 1) '<---PN_CurrentScan is the name of text box
        EnteredPN = Left(EnteredPN, 12)
        PN_CurrentScan.Value = ""
```

After making some corrections on the scanned data I basically write it to a sheet in the workbook. Then I also have a pivot table in the same workbook which uses this scanned data as source and counts how many parts scanned from each part number.

**2. Current Status:** This ListBox contains all the part numbers scanned (Coming from the pivot table mentioned above) and waiting to be scanned (Coming from another worksheet). Then it refreshes it self every time a new part is scanned.

**3. ListBox Scroll Bar:** Since I have very long part number list it is not possible for me to fit everything on the screen that is why listbox creates this scroll bar.

Enough with the background I think :)

So if we come to my concern. Since my collages using cordless scanner to do this operation sometimes they don't have the chance to see the screen so they can not understand if the cursor is on the "Scanned Part Number Text Box" or not. That is why I need focus to be on that box no matter what happens (Of course we can not do anything if warehouse burns down, earth quake or tsunami hits the place but let do not think about those).

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

1. First of all I disabled all the remaining objects from properties window
2. Then I diabled tab stops of all controls:

   ```
   Dim contr As Control
   For Each contr In ScannerInterface.Controls
       On Error Resume Next
       contr.TabStop = False
   Next
   ScannerInterface.PN_CurrentScan.TabStop = True
   ```
3. Added setfocus property to all button clicks:

   ```
   Me.PN_CurrentScan.SetFocus
   ```
4. Added setfocus property to listbox click:

   ```
   Private Sub CurrentStatus_List_Click()
       Me.PN_CurrentScan.SetFocus
   End Sub
   ```
5. Added set focus to enter and exit events of listbox however this did not work:

   ```
   Private Sub CurrentStatus_List_Enter()
   Me.PN_CurrentScan.SetFocus
   End Sub

   Private Sub CurrentStatus_List_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   Me.PN_CurrentScan.SetFocus
   End Sub
   ```

So, with all these counter measures I have managed to improve up to somepoint, only concern remaining is when I click on the scroll bar next to the listbox, text box lose focus and without clicking in the textbox I could not manage to set the focus again. I tried all events with listbox non of them worked. Is there any way to solve this problem or do I need to deal with this? Thanks in advance for your supports.

SOLUTION:

Thanks to @Rory we have managed to solve my problem. As he noticed and explained in the answer below, both my textbox and listbox were in frames. I have tried several setfocus options but I always gave the focus to the textbox. However, solution was to give the focus to the frame which was containing the target textbox:

```
    Private Sub CurrentStatus_Frame_Enter() '<-- Enter event of the frame which contains listbox
        Me.PN_CurrentScan.SetFocus '<-- Setfocus to target textbox
        Me.Scanned_Frame.SetFocus '<-- Setfocus to frame which contains target textbox
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the `Enter` event to set focus back to the Textbox.

Comment: Hello, thank for the heads up. I have already tried that. I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: Which version of Excel - it works for me with 2010.

Comment: I am also using 2010, this is strange. We are talking about `Enter` event of listbox right?

Comment: Yes we are. But I just noticed that the listbox is inside a Frame - use the Frame's `Enter` event instead.

Comment: Nope, no good. I tried frame too however when I click the scroll bar cursor disappears from text box. Thanks anyway

Comment: I can't replicate. Can you post a workbook somewhere?

Comment: I am at work and security limitations do not allow me. I will delete content and try it at home, may be you can have a loot later. I will give you a heads up when I upload it. Thank you very much.

Comment: OK. One quick thought in the meantime. Set focus to the **Frame** containing the textbox from the `Enter` event of the listbox's container frame.

Comment: YESSSSSS. Man, you are life saver. Now I can have a nice sleep :) I did exactly what you suggested in your last comment and it worked. Thank you very much. If you write this as answer I can give a green it so we can close the topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having (eventually) noticed that both of your controls are inside container Frame controls, you can actually use the `Enter` event of the Frame that contains the listbox to set focus to the Frame that contains the textbox, rather than to the textbox itself.